# Word search puzzle on vb

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user to enter 10 words they would like hidden in a word search puzzle. How do I place the words in the grid?

This is what I did but I keep getting this error

> messageSystem.IndexOutOfRangeException
> Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Code:

```
Sub Words()
        wordcount = 0
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("choose word")
            word = Console.ReadLine
            Showdirection()
            Console.WriteLine("choose row")
            row = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("choose column")
            col = Console.ReadLine
            grid(row, col) = word(0)
            For i = 1 To Len(word)
                Select Case choice
                    Case "1"
                        col = col + 1
                    Case "2"
                        col = col - 1
                    Case "3"
                        row = row - 1

                    Case "4"
                        row = row + 1

                    Case "5"
                        col = col + 1
                        row = row - 1
                    Case "6"
                        col = col - 1
                        row = row + 1

                    Case "7"
                        col = col + 1
                        row = row + 1

                    Case "8"
                        col = col - 1
                        row = row + 1
                End Select
                grid(row, col) = word(i)
            Next
            wordcount = wordcount + 1
        Loop Until wordcount = 10
    End Sub
```

Also, once all the words are placed in the grid, how do i fill the remaining spaces with random letters?

This is my code so far

```
  Dim grid(14, 14) As String
    Dim choice As Integer
    Dim word As String
    Dim wordcount As Integer = 0
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Sub outputgrid()
        For i = 0 To 14
            For j = 0 To 14
                Console.Write(grid(i, j))
            Next j
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next i
    End Sub
    Sub setupgrid()
        For i = 0 To 14
            For j = 0 To 14
                grid(i, j) = ""
            Next j
        Next i
    End Sub
    Sub Main(args As String())
        setupgrid()
        outputgrid()
        Words()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Sub Words()
        wordcount = 0
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("choose word")
            word = Console.ReadLine
            Showdirection()
            Console.WriteLine("choose row")
            row = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("choose column")
            col = Console.ReadLine
            grid(row, col) = word(0)
            For i = 1 To Len(word)
                Select Case choice
                    Case "1"
                        col = col + 1
                    Case "2"
                        col = col - 1
                    Case "3"
                        row = row - 1

                    Case "4"
                        row = row + 1

                    Case "5"
                        col = col + 1
                        row = row - 1
                    Case "6"
                        col = col - 1
                        row = row + 1

                    Case "7"
                        col = col + 1
                        row = row + 1

                    Case "8"
                        col = col - 1
                        row = row + 1
                End Select
                grid(row, col) = word(i)
            Next
            wordcount = wordcount + 1
        Loop Until wordcount = 10
    End Sub
    Sub Showdirection()
        Console.WriteLine("choose direction")
        Console.WriteLine("1 horizontal- left to right")
        Console.WriteLine("2 Horizontal -Right to Left")
        Console.WriteLine("3 Vertical -Down")
        Console.WriteLine("4 Vertical -Up")
        Console.WriteLine("5 Diagonal – Down L To R")
        Console.WriteLine("6 Diagonal – Down R To L ")
        Console.WriteLine("7 Diagonal – Up L To R ")
        Console.WriteLine("8 Diagonal – Up R To L ")
        choice = Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to reword you question some.  Can you please update your question with exactly how the above is code is not meeting your requirements.

Comment: In `Words()`  you ask for a word, direction, and starting position, but I see no logic to determine if there is enough ROOM for the word at that position/direction. The error most likely stems from you trying to insert the next letter outside the bounds of the puzzle. Also, there is zero logic to determine if the word will OVERWRITE a word that was written previously. So you need to check both that there is enough room for the word and that there are no existing letters in that spot. Words can overlap, but they must have the same letter at the intersection point, which is harder to check for.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code. You are doing implicit casting from string to Integer and back. Once you do that you will see that some things need some explicit casting (and, I am not going to do this, but you should validate the user's entry)

```vb
choice = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
' there are more examples of this you need to fix
' but what if the user enters a non-number? You should handle that case
```

And the case statement operates on an Integer but your cases are strings. Change to Integers

```vb
Select Case choice
    Case 1
        col = col + 1
    Case 2
        col = col - 1
...
```

As for your code not working, I'll help you come up with an explanation (this is what you should have put in your question):

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException
>
>   Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.

It's easy to see that your For loop isn't set up properly. Keep in mind arrays are zero-based in vb.net.

Change

```vb
For i = 1 To Len(word)
```

to

```vb
For i = 0 To Len(word) - 1
```

To fill the rest of the empty cells, use a method

```vb
Private Sub fillEmptyCells()
    Dim random As New Random()
    For i = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(1)
            If grid(i, j) = "" Then
                ' ascii characters 97 to 122 are all the lower-case letters
                grid(i, j) = Chr(random.Next(97, 123)).ToString()
            End If
            ' this will clean up your entry in the case the user entered a capital letter
            grid(i, j) = grid(i, j).ToLower()
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

call it at the end

```vb
Sub Main(args As String())
    setupgrid()
    outputgrid()
    Words()
    fillEmptyCells()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: how do i fix error System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array? also if i want uppercase letters should i change this ` grid(i, j) = Chr(random.Next(97, 123)).ToString()`  into ` grid(i, j) = Chr(random.Next(65, 90)).ToString()`

Comment: The fix is in my answer i.e. `For i = 0 To Len(word) - 1`. Random.Next second argument is exclusive so you would need it to be 91 i.e. `Chr(random.Next(65, 91)).ToString()` then the `grid(i, j) = grid(i, j).ToLower()` should be changed to `grid(i, j) = grid(i, j).ToUpper()`