# Word search puzzle on vb, how do I show the completed grid after the words have been entered?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user to enter 10 words they would like hidden in a word search puzzle then show the completed grid.

How do I show the completed grid after the words have been entered? when the words are entered the program doesn't do anything until I press enter which closes it

code

```
   Dim grid(14, 14) As String
    Dim choice As Integer
    Dim word As String
    Dim wordcount As Integer = 0
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Sub outputgrid()
        For i = 0 To 14
            For j = 0 To 14
                Console.Write(grid(i, j))
            Next j
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next i

    End Sub
    Sub setupgrid()
        'sets the grid
        For i = 0 To 14
            For j = 0 To 14
                grid(i, j) = ""
            Next j
        Next i
    End Sub
    Sub Main()
        setupgrid()
        outputgrid()
        Words()
        fillEmptyCells()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Sub Words()

        wordcount = 0
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("choose word")
            word = CInt(Console.ReadLine)
            Showdirection()
            Console.WriteLine("choose row")
            row = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
            Console.WriteLine("choose column")
            col = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
            grid(row, col) = word(0)
            For i = 0 To Len(word) - 1
                Select Case choice
                    Case 1
                        col = col + 1
                    Case 2
                        col = col - 1
                    Case 3
                        row = row + 1

                    Case 4
                        row = row - 1

                    Case 5
                        col = col + 1
                        row = row + 1
                    Case 6
                        col = col - 1
                        row = row + 1

                    Case 7
                        col = col + 1
                        row = row - 1

                    Case 8
                        col = col - 1
                        row = row - 1
                End Select
                grid(row, col) = word(i)
            Next
            wordcount = wordcount + 1
        Loop Until wordcount = 10
    End Sub
    Sub Showdirection()
        Console.WriteLine("choose direction")
        Console.WriteLine("1 horizontal- left to right")
        Console.WriteLine("2 Horizontal -Right to Left")
        Console.WriteLine("3 Vertical -Down")
        Console.WriteLine("4 Vertical -Up")
        Console.WriteLine("5 Diagonal – Down L To R")
        Console.WriteLine("6 Diagonal – Down R To L ")
        Console.WriteLine("7 Diagonal – Up L To R ")
        Console.WriteLine("8 Diagonal – Up R To L ")
        choice = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    End Sub
    Private Sub fillEmptyCells()

        Dim random As New Random()
        For i = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(0)
            For j = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(1)
                If grid(i, j) = "" Then

                    grid(i, j) = Chr(random.Next(65, 90)).ToString()
                End If

                grid(i, j) = grid(i, j).ToUpper()
            Next
        Next
        End

    End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [word search puzzle on vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384137/word-search-puzzle-on-vb)

Comment: @Calaf no he wants someone to write code to finally display the grid. He hasn't tried anything yet however according to the code above, which does incorporate my fixes from the previous question.

Comment: It `"doesn't do anything"` because you have not written any code to make it do anything. Write some code, and if it doesn't work then come here with a question about it.

Comment: how do I write a code to make it display the grid? Don't know where to start

Comment: If you used a DataTable instead of a 2 dimensional array of String (grid), you could set the DataSource Property of a DataGridView to the the DataTable.

Comment: Oops! Never mind. I see this is console app.

Comment: `word = CInt(Console.ReadLine)`  `word` is declared `As String`. Why are you converting a String to an Integer and then trying to assign it to a String variable. Turn on Option Strict now and forever. Project Properties -> Compile tab. Also for future projects Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the problem well, but let's try to find a solution.
You already have a method that allows you to print what you've entered into the grid, and that's `outputgrid()`.
If you want to see the result at the end, you need to change the main as follows:

```
Sub Main()
    setupgrid()
    outputgrid() 'This the initial empty grid...
    Words()
    fillEmptyCells()
    outputgrid() 'This is the filled grid
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

If you want to see the result after each user action, you need to add the same thing in the sub `Words()` loop:

```
Sub Words()
    wordcount = 0
    Do
        '* your original code *
        outputgrid() 'Grid with current data
    Loop Until wordcount = 10
End Sub
```

One more thing... If I'm not misunderstood, you're trying to put words in the grid, right?
With the lines

```
Console.WriteLine("choose word")
word = CInt(Console.ReadLine)
```

you are allowing the user to enter only numbers (due to `CInt`).

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of most of the Module level variables and moved them to where they are used. If a variable is only used in a single method it should be declared as a local variable.

I got rid of the `setupgrid` method and changed `fillEmptyCells` to check for `Null` or `Empty`.

Don't call `outputgrid` until after you filled the grid.

To stop the errors in `Words` method, I added an `If` statement that checked if you `row` and `col` were in range of the grid.

In the `fillEmptyCells` method I got rid of the line where you called `ToUpper`. The ASCII codes you provided are all uppercase characters. Also, in the call to `Random.Next`, I changed the second parameter to `91` so you could include `Z`.
`Next` includes the first parameter and excludes the second.

It will be easier to pick out the words from the grid because they may be in lower case. This might be good while you are debugging but afterwards in the `Words` method `Dim word = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper` makes the puzzle harder.

I think you will see that input words may be overwritten. You could add checks to prevent this. If you want to allow an additional word when a word won't fit put `wordcount -= 1` directly before the `Exit For`.

```
Private grid(14, 14) As String

Sub outputgrid()
    For i = 0 To 14
        For j = 0 To 14
            Console.Write(grid(i, j))
        Next j
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Words()
    fillEmptyCells()
    outputgrid()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub Words()
    Dim wordcount As Integer
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("choose word")
        Dim word = Console.ReadLine '.ToUpper after debugging
        Dim DirectionChoice = Showdirection()
        Console.WriteLine("choose row")
        Dim row = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("choose column")
        Dim col = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        grid(row, col) = word(0) 'First letter of word
        For i = 1 To Len(word) - 1 'don't start at zero, you have already assigned the zero element
            Select Case DirectionChoice
                Case 1 'horizontal- left to right
                    col = col + 1
                Case 2 'Horizontal -Right to Left
                    col = col - 1
                Case 3 'Vertical -Down
                    row = row + 1
                Case 4 'Vertical -Up
                    row = row - 1
                Case 5 'Diagonal – Down L To R
                    col = col + 1
                    row = row + 1
                Case 6 'Diagonal – Down R To L
                    col = col - 1
                    row = row + 1
                Case 7 'Diagonal – Up L To R
                    col = col + 1
                    row = row - 1
                Case 8 'Diagonal – Up R To L
                    col = col - 1
                    row = row - 1
            End Select
            If col > 14 OrElse col < 0 OrElse row > 14 OrElse row < 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Word won't fit")
                Exit For
            End If
            grid(row, col) = word(i)
        Next
        wordcount += 1
    Loop Until wordcount = 2 '10
End Sub
Private Function Showdirection() As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("choose direction")
    Console.WriteLine("1 horizontal- left to right")
    Console.WriteLine("2 Horizontal -Right to Left")
    Console.WriteLine("3 Vertical -Down")
    Console.WriteLine("4 Vertical -Up")
    Console.WriteLine("5 Diagonal – Down L To R")
    Console.WriteLine("6 Diagonal – Down R To L ")
    Console.WriteLine("7 Diagonal – Up L To R ")
    Console.WriteLine("8 Diagonal – Up R To L ")
    Dim choice = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Return choice
End Function
Private Sub fillEmptyCells()
    Dim random As New Random()
    For i = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j = 0 To grid.GetUpperBound(1)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(grid(i, j)) Then '<---
                grid(i, j) = Chr(random.Next(65, 91)).ToString() 'Next includes the first parameter and excludes the second
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```